# How to reroute form data from client to some microservice via Node.js?

Tags: node.js, file, express, multipartform-data

I have created an intermediate backend on Node.js to talk to multiple microservices my app depends on. All is good so far. The issue I'm unable to resolve is with file handling. My client is sending files to the Node layer in the form of Formdata and I want to reroute the same form data to some particular microservice which expects the file in the form of form data as well. I'm using [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) middleware to extract the file from the `req` object but it gives me the file data with the following property:

```
req.files.file = {
  data:Buffer(47643) [37, 80, 68, …]
  encoding:"7bit"
  md5:() => …
  mimetype: "application/pdf"
  mv: function (filePath, callback) { … }
  name:"somefile.pdf"
  truncated:false
}
```

**How to create the same form data that client has send outta this object?**

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to sent this file object to specific api after client send a request to your microservies and server recieved that. your file data is accessible with `req` object in all express middlewares.

you can route between middlewares or next routing easily thanks to `next` method of express.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
  if (/*go to next middleware*/)
     next();
  else if (/*go to next route*/)
     next('route');
}, function (req, res) {
  // [next middleware]
  // req.files.foo is accessible
});

// specific api should stand exactly after receiver api
app.post('/anyRoute', function(req, res) {
  // [next route]
  console.log(req.files.foo); // object file is already accessible
});
```

if you want to make a request from server you can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) module.

Comment: how to send request from you client now?

Comment: what do you mean to  'reroute from client  to some microservices with "node.js"'? node.js is a backend lang as you know so how it should handle client side? your question is confusing, please clarify more in your question and append expanded code.